# Triggering label with another hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

if I have a `hotkey:` with only one colon how would I trigger it with an `a::` (keybind)?

```
help:
  Gui, Add, Text,, Help:
  Gui, Add, Text,, Welcome to the Help screen
  ...
Return

a::
  ; Trigger Help here
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

help: is a label, not a hotkey. You can also go to the label with `Goto, help`
but then the return command will stop the script, instead of, as with Gosub, returning to the row after the Gosub command.